# How to find steady predator/prey matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-modeling

so I’m trying to find the steady state of this matrix but it’s not a Markov chain. It’s for the second problem on the picture to find what predatory value makes both populations stable.  Through trial and error I figured out p=.16 for the matrix to converge to a stable population but I don’t know how to do it other than trial and error. My professor said in class to find the steady state of the matrix but I thought you could only do that if it was a markov chain? 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrgAp.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I would suggest that you type the relevant information from the linked image in your question. You're much more likely to get a helpful answer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we've reached the steady state $X$, we want $AX=X$, so $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$.  Therefore, we must choose $p$ so that $A$ has an eigenvalue of $1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh that makes sense now. I can do it from there. thank you so much!

Comment: @OlyveaPancerella My pleasure.